# Gradle error for TMessagesProj'. executing external native build for ndkBuild

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, telegram

i was downloaded the official telegram source from this link : 
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
when i try to run this app , the gradle sync fail & gives me the following error :

Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':TMessagesProj'.

> executing external native build for ndkBuild C:\Users\Moonwalker\Desktop\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk

alson downloaded the ndk bundle ...no success

my sdk version : 23

andriod studio 2.3.1

win 10 .

anyone can help ?

Comment: did you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You must add recursive to `git clone`. Something like this:

```
git clone --recursive git@github.com:DrKLO/Telegram.git
```

Or this:

```
git clone --recursive http://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram.git
```